# what is the best practices for building android with gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

according the guide  here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide
i was a little puzzled.

For instance,if i set up  multi-projects as the file structures below:

```
 MyProject/
         + app/
         + libraries/
                   + lib1/
                   + lib2/
```

we could setup a `settings.gradle`  file with

```
        `include ':app', ':libraries:lib1', ':libraries:lib2'`
```

These projects is create by ourself.

But,

1. if we clone a third party library such as ActionBarSherlock
2. and clone another app, github for android which requires the ActionBarSherlock
3. i want share the source ActionBarSherlock to github-android in Android Studio(or Intellij)

   ```
     ActionBarSherlock/
               -settings.gradle
               +actionBarSherlock
               +actionBarSherlock-i18n

     github-android/
            - build.gradle
            + app
            + test
   ```

they are exist in diffrent parent directory with diffrent root project.

how should i assign the compile project path in `build.gradle`? How could the  github android client get the relevant library?

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
}
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to compile `actionbarsherlock`? If not, it looks like you can download it as a jar dependency in `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

ok,i have gave up the gradle temporary and choose maven-android-plugin + Intellij as my favorite gadgets. 
as  Maven-android-plugin GettingStarted: https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted  mentioned:

> If you have JUnit tests that don't call any Android APIs (directly or transitively), put them in src/test/java so JUnit runs them locally and more quickly than if run on the device.

I put my Robolectric+Junit in the src/test in the main app module and  Instrument Test in the test module.

At present, i feels they work fine.